# Give to DockLayoutPanel CENTER region a style name property?

Tags: java, gwt, docklayoutpanel

I created a new DockLayoutPanel in GWT and I want to give a style name on the CENTER section on the panel.
Any suggestions?

This is the docklayoutpanel:

```
private DockLayoutPanel doc;

public void onModuleLoad(){


        headerWidget = new HeaderWidget();

        searchWidget = new SearchWidget();

        storeWidget = new StoreWidget();

        doc = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);

        doc.addNorth(headerWidget, 10);
        doc.addSouth(new HTML("Footer"), 5);
        doc.addWest(WidgetWest(), 20);
        doc.add(searchWidget);

        RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        root.add(doc);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
searchWidget.addStyleName("myStyle");
```

Comment: Ohhh, true!! I feel so dummy now! Thanks